# How to get the last transaction of each player - SQL Solution

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where I store all transactions made in a game ([picture of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rNW1.png)). Now I want to get the value of the last transaction for each player.

I already tried:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp), value, account_id
FROM transactions
GROUP BY account_id;
```

Here I get the right time and account_id, but not the right value.

Is it possible to solve this problem only with SQL?

Comment: MySQL version???

Comment: It's version 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table 
where id in (select MAX(id) from table group by account_id)
```

Comment: This assumes the ids are in same order as timestamp. This is true in most cases but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @SalmanA how can i fix it?

Comment: You can use correlation e.g. `where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from transactions as x where account_id = transactions.account_id)`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8 or later you can use window functions for this:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by account_id order by timestamp desc) as rn
    from transactions
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you!! Unfortunatly my MYSQL version is 5.7 and I can't upgrade it.

Comment: Use the comment below the other answer.